# Uninstalled apps still show up on "Apps installed on" in Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, uninstallation

I already uninstalled the unwanted applications from my device, but they still show up  on "**Apps installed on**"  in my Google Play account.
Does it mean that the apps I got rid of are still stored in my phone?

Comment: It can take a little time for the web-based Play Store to see what is and isn't installed on your device. You can facilitate that by running the Play Store app on your device. That should kickstart the sync process between your device and the web.

Answer (score 13):

In the Play store there is a 'installed' tab which as the name implies is of currently installed applications. The 'all' tab shows apps which have ever been installed on the device.

If you don't want a application to show up in this list, then from the phone open Play store, go into your My Apps and on the All tab you can click the circular remove icon to the right of the app will remove it from your Play account.

This is what it should look like:
[image: This is what it should look like.]

Comment: One note about this: if you accidentally select more than one app, the X will be greyed out (or possibly missing).  This can inadvertently happen if you highlight one app, then try to remove a different one, IIRC.

Comment: I removed the app and it still says I have the app installed...

Answer (score 1):

I have a Motorola Moto G, with Android 4.4.4 installed on it, so your version might be slightly different.

On your device go to 'Google Play', and go to the 'Menu' (the 3 horizontal bars on the top left of the screen), the Menu should pop-up from the left side of the screen. Select 'My Apps' and a new screen should pop-up, the 'My Apps' screen.

On the top you will see two choices, 'installed' & 'all'.  The first option is pretty self explanatory; the second choice lists ALL of the applications you have ever installed or uninstalled on your device.  If you go down the list you will see that the apps are listed and neatly separated by little rectangles. Notice that the uninstalled apps have a little 'x' in the top right corner of the rectangle. Tap it and the device will ask you if you want to remove it from the list.

That is how you remove it from the device. It'll be removed from the Googe Play site when the phone syncs with Google's servers.

Comment: This method works on my Samsung Galaxy sIII, too.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes a while until the Play Store syncs with what's installed and what's not. You just have to wait and I haven't any method of making it sync faster.

Comment: You'll be waiting a while. I had uninstalled apps sitting in my acct for over a year.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting cache and data of the Play store app solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings > Accounts > Google, and click the "Sync all" button at the bottom.

Answer (score -2):

Try moving the app to the SD Card and uninstall it, if persist move it again to the phone and uninstall it, it works in my LG G3 when that happens

Comment: That will do nothing except waste time. Uninstalling a program is not supposed to remove it from the Play Store history.