# Adding uninstalled apps to wishlist in Play store

Tags: google-play-store

There is something in the Play store app that bugs me ever since I found out the problem exists: I cannot add previously uninstalled apps to the wishlist.

I made my research and found [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2620417) on XDA where they acknowledge the problem, then [this suggestion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/34ndhv/suggestions_for_wishlist_improvments_in_the/cqxryp0) on Reddit which didn't even get a response and this useless [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/play/cfLE-TdNIi4) on the Google Play help forum. I didn't find any other direct reference to the problem.

I tried to clear cache for the Play Store, but like with the guy that opened the XDA thread, it didn't work. I made sure to delete the app from the 'All apps' on all my devices. The web interface still shows 'Installed', I think this can be related. I think the problem lies in the Play Store, without anything the user can do to overcome the issue.

So my question is: does anybody know of Google acknowledging/addressing the issue in the future? Or, if there exists a workaround?

Comment: Seems [the root cause of this issue](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33172/uninstalled-apps-still-show-up-on-apps-installed-on-in-google-play-store?rq=1) got worse...