# This app will not install or uninstall on my phone

Tags: installation

I am on android, Sony Xperia M C1904 model. There is an app called "SnapChat" that I cannot install or uninstall from my phone.

What happened earlier was that I didn't have enough storage and after i made enough storage, I tried to install it again, but it tells me I have it installed.

After lots of googling, cache clearing, and removing from my "Apps", this app still would not let me install.

I have tried to remove the listing on "My Apps" from my Google Play Store (it is gone now), and it still tells me i have it installed. I looked inside my phone's 'all apps" and it doesn't even list SnapChat. I had another app called "Sky Night" that I got rid of a while back and through this method I managed to properly "remove it". On the app store, it says I have it installed but it lets me install it again at least. But this one app would just not go away or get on my phone.

[For reference I used techniques from here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33172/uninstalled-apps-still-show-up-on-apps-installed-on-in-google-play-store)

Comment: Get the package ID of the app in question, then use `adb uninstall` to attempt to uninstall it properly. If it succeeds then it'll be a thorough uninstall; if it doesn't at least it will return a reason why it failed, which you can edit into your question and let us know.

Comment: @AndyYan, how do I get the package id...? I am not sure how to use the second step either...is it something I should open?

Comment: Play Store link contains the ID. If you don't know any one of these, just go look them up - basic for Android enthusiasts.

Comment: Or try it the other way around: `adb install -r snapchat.apk` should force a re-install (`-r` of an installed package – i.e. install the `.apk` over an already installed version of the same package.